# Creating a feed => NoMethodError: undefined method for ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-many-through, model-associations, rails-postgresql

I am implementing a feed of all cards belonging to the tags a user has subscribed to and I get the following error. It's probably something trivial but I can't pinpoint what needs work.

NoMethodError: undefined method `cards' Tag::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fbaa46239f8>

Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cards, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :cards

  has_many :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :subscribed_tags, through: :subscriptions, source: :tag
end
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cards, through: :taggings
  has_many :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :subscribers, through: :subscriptions, source: :user
end
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings    
  def self.tagged_with(name)
    Tag.find_by_name!(name).cards
  end
  def self.tag_counts
    Tag.select("tags.*, count(taggings.tag_id) as count").
    joins(:taggings).group("taggings.tag_id")
  end
  def tag_list
     tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
  end
  def tag_list=(names)
    self.tags = names.split(",").map do |n|
       Tag.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end
end
```

What I am really trying to do is to run current_user.subscribed_tags.cards and retrieve an array of cards I can reorder and output as a timeline.

Thanks

Comment: You want to retrieve array of tags of current_user OR array of cards of subscribed_tags of current_user?

Comment: woops, typo: an array of cards of subscubed_tags of current_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subscribed_tags` - it's a scope (`where(user: self)`), you can call `where` or `join` on them but not an item methods.

In your case you want to use a `scope`

```
class Card
  scope :with_subscription, -> { joins(tags: :subscriptions) }
end

# In controller
current_user.cards.with_subscription.order('cards.created_at DESC')
```

You can imagine `current_user.cards` like another form of `Cards.where(user: current_user)`. Once you tell that you will retrieve `Card` array - it cannot be changed. You cannot do `user.cards.subscriptions` or `User.where(id: user).cards.tags` the only you can do it's filter.

Next we filter with `joins(:subscriptions)`. It will give us inner join, so we get cards belonged to user that have subscriptions. And it's a scope we can modify further passing for example an order.

[activerecord join associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations)

Comment: I get an undefined method with_subscriptions for the Card class, when I account for the extra "s" I still get the error... Any thoughts? After reading the guide, am I really querying to RETURN All Cards In tags to which the current user has subscribed to

Comment: I forgot a colon. Try again.

Comment: Still get the error "unexpected '{', expecting keyword_end scope :with_subscription { joins(:subscriptions) }"

i'm using rails 4.2.1 if that's any help

Comment: I'm really mustn't to depend on memory in such things. Try again. Eventually we go through this.

Comment: haha no worries, thanks. I get an activerecord::configurationerror. and Association named 'subscriptions' was not found on Card; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: Can you find me in skype? We figure it out and then I correct the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80675/discussion-between-astery-and-ghost).